# Got wrong value while detecting available disk space on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, disk

I follow http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/27/maciphone-show-availble-useable-diskspace/
and [how do i find out iphone Disk Space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606474/how-do-i-find-out-iphone-disk-space)
to detect the available disk space. However, seem that the result is not correct

I tested on iphone 4 ios 4.2.1.

in Setting, 
Capacity is 29.1 G
Availability is 24.2 G

I want to get 24.2 G value. So I followed the tutorial I mentioned above.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        .....

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
        NSLog(@"path %@", paths);

        struct statfs tStats;
        statfs([[paths lastObject] UTF8String], &tStats);

        NSString *sizeType;

        float total_space = (float)(tStats.f_blocks * tStats.f_bsize);  
        NSLog(@"total space: %f", total_space);
        NSLog(@"total space: %@", convertUnit(total_space));

        float free_space = (float)(tStats.f_bfree * tStats.f_bsize);
        NSLog(@"free space: %f", free_space);
        NSLog(@"free space: %@", convertUnit(free_space));

        float free_space2 = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);      
        NSLog(@"free blocks avail to non-superuser: %f", free_space2);
        NSLog(@"free blocks avail to non-superuser: %@", convertUnit(free_space2));

        uint32_t block_size = (tStats.f_bsize);     
        NSLog(@"block size: %d", block_size);
        NSLog(@"block size: %@", convertUnit(block_size));
        .....
}       

NSString* convertUnit (float value) {
    NSString *sizeType;
    if (value > 1024)
    {
        //Kilobytes
        value = value / 1024;

        sizeType = @" KB";
    }

    if (value > 1024)
    {
        //Megabytes
        value = value / 1024;

        sizeType = @" MB";
    }

    if (value > 1024)
    {
        //Gigabytes
        value = value / 1024;

        sizeType = @" GB";
    }

    return [[@"Available Disk Space: " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.2f", value] stringByAppendingString:sizeType];

}
```

RESULT:

```
total space: 17363854862722269184.000000
total space: Available Disk Space: 16171350016.00 GB

free space: 17743592094095638528.000000
free space: Available Disk Space: 16525007872.00 GB

free blocks avail to non-superuser: 17432956969504735232.00000
free blocks avail to non-superuser: Available Disk Space: 16235706368.00 GB

block size: 803203484
block size: Available Disk Space: 765.99 MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do more search about file system of iphone, I found that iphone has 2 partitions: one for os and another for user data. The values I got is the attributes of OS partitions. So I changed the path to be 'private/var' which is the path of data partition. As a result, I got the correct value for free disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace {

    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

    if (dictionary) {  
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {  
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);  
    }  

    return ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll);
}
```

This will give you total free Space in MB